# When i'm sending the mail it's not delivering to the recipent here is the log ........can anyone help me what i need to configure?

Tags: email, gmail, mail-server, sendmail

```
mail -s "test mail" recipient@domain.com < messagebody.txt

Dec 16 06:45:23 Ambidextrous postfix/pickup[16021]: D493648123F: uid=1000 from=<praveen@Ambidextrous>
Dec 16 06:45:23 Ambidextrous postfix/cleanup[18325]: D493648123F: message-id=<20191216011523.D493648123F@Ambidextrous>
Dec 16 06:45:23 Ambidextrous postfix/qmgr[16022]: D493648123F: from=<praveen@Ambidextrous>, size=467, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 06:45:24 Ambidextrous postfix/smtp[18327]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[2404:6800:4003:c03::6d]:587: Network is unreachable
Dec 16 06:45:25 Ambidextrous postfix/smtp[18327]: D493648123F: to=<recipient_mail@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[74.125.24.108]:587, delay=1.6, delays=0.1/0.03/1.3/0.2, dsn=5.7.0, status=bounced (host smtp.gmail.com[74.125.24.108] said: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError f81sm20379329pfa.118 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Dec 16 06:45:25 Ambidextrous postfix/cleanup[18325]: A19DA481245: message-id=<20191216011525.A19DA481245@Ambidextrous>
Dec 16 06:45:25 Ambidextrous postfix/bounce[18328]: D493648123F: sender non-delivery notification: A19DA481245
Dec 16 06:45:25 Ambidextrous postfix/qmgr[16022]: A19DA481245: from=<>, size=2688, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 06:45:25 Ambidextrous postfix/qmgr[16022]: D493648123F: removed
Dec 16 06:45:25 Ambidextrous postfix/local[18329]: A19DA481245: to=<praveen@Ambidextrous>, relay=local, delay=0.08, delays=0.05/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Dec 16 06:45:25 Ambidextrous postfix/qmgr[16022]: A19DA481245: removed
```

Comment: @OrganicMarble IPv6 errors out, two lines down is the actual error: `Dec 16 06:45:25 Ambidextrous postfix/smtp[18327]: D493648123F: to=<recipient_mail@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[74.125.24.108]:587, delay=1.6, delays=0.1/0.03/1.3/0.2, dsn=5.7.0, status=bounced (host smtp.gmail.com[74.125.24.108] said: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError f81sm20379329pfa.118 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command))`

Comment: @Praveen is this Postfix set to use GMail as a relay for all mail being sent from this box?  Because the way it's erroring indicates that it *wants* you to use SASL auth to authenticate your relay to send email messages.

Comment: @OrganicMarble if you wish to continue this discussion between us, then let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102236/discussion-between-thomas-ward-and-organic-marble).  I've removed the other comments as to not derail Praveen giving more info back to us in response to our requests for info.

Comment: @ThomasWard yes it's a postfix server

Comment: the question is *how is Postfix configured*.  Did you configure POstfix to try and send using smtp.gmail.com or Google Mail as a direct relay for sending all emails out?  The error I indicated from your logs above seems to suggest this, I need confirmation to know whether you configured your server this way.

Comment: @ThomasWard yes i used smtp.gmail.com to relay for sending all emails out.

Comment: and you set up SMTP SASL properly per the answer, yes?  The error suggests you have no SASL.

Comment: If you are using Two-Factor Authentication (2FA) for your GMail that you make sure that you use https://security.google.com and setup an App Password that you can use in the `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` file. Also see: https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/configure-postfix-to-send-mail-using-gmail-and-google-apps-on-debian-or-ubuntu/

Comment: Here is my main.cf file [ https://github.com/praveenkanjarla/Postfix-config.git ]

is there anything else to modify?

Comment: Is `Ambidextrous.com` the name of your system?  You might need to change that in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to just `hostname = Ambidextrous`  Also, check your gmail and see if you are using Two-Factor Authentication.  I had a problem with mine authenticating because I use the 2FA so once I did the App Password it worked every time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify a valid FROM email adress, or GMail will not accept to send.
Find some examples here: https://www.binarytides.com/linux-mailx-command/

```
echo "This is the message body" | mail -s "Subject: Test Mail" -aFrom:aN\<ValidSender@gmail.com\> recipient@domain.com
```

FYI, if you want to send email from scripts or command line with all advanced features, a good workaround could be to use the [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) library : attachments, html & text format, [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail), [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)...

---

You may also review your PostFix configuration
`/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` must contain your GMail account informations on a line looking like this:
`[smtp.gmail.com]:587    username@gmail.com:password`
`/etc/postfix/main.cf` must refer to the previous file with `smtp_sasl_password_maps`
Then use `postmap` to complie the sasl passwd file

Comment: yes my setup is same as this  
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    username@gmail.com:password

my password contain a period(.) does it cause any conflict?

Comment: @Praveen : no matter about characters. Did you try the mail command with FROM ?

Comment: yes i tried 

**echo "This is the message body" | mail -s "Subject: Test Mail" -aFrom:aN\<ValidSender@gmail.com\> recipient@domain.com**

And I got the same error as in the question :(

Comment: @Praveen u have to use a valid sender email address for the FROM field - If SO, then you must review your postfix config

Comment: here is my main.cf of my postfix setup  https://github.com/praveenkanjarla/Postfix-config.git
 does anything need to modify ?